# Cannot connect to Kudu from Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-kudu

## I cannot properly connect to Kudu from Spark, error says "Kudu master has no leader"

- CDH 5.14
- Kudu 1.6
- Spark 1.6.0 standalone and 2.2.0

When I use Impala in HUE to create and query kudu tables, it works flawlessly.

However, connecting from Spark throws some errors I cannot decipher.

I have tried using both pyspark and spark-shell. With spark shell I had to use spark 1.6 instead of 2.2 because some maven dependencies problems, that I have localized but not been able to fix. More info here.

---

### Case 1: using pyspark2 (Spark 2.2.0)

```
$ pyspark2 --master yarn --jars /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.14.0-1.cdh5.14.0.p0.24/lib/kudu/kudu-spark2_2.11.jar

> df = sqlContext.read.format('org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu').options(**{"kudu.master":"172.17.0.43:7077", "kudu.table":"impala::default.test"}).load()

18/03/02 10:23:27 WARN client.ConnectToCluster: Error receiving response from 172.17.0.43:7077
org.apache.kudu.client.RecoverableException: [peer master-172.17.0.43:7077] encountered a read timeout; closing the channel
        at org.apache.kudu.client.Connection.exceptionCaught(Connection.java:412)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.Connection.handleUpstream(Connection.java:239)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.exceptionCaught(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:153)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireExceptionCaught(Channels.java:536)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler.readTimedOut(ReadTimeoutHandler.java:236)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler$ReadTimeoutTask$1.run(ReadTimeoutHandler.java:276)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.ChannelRunnableWrapper.run(ChannelRunnableWrapper.java:40)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.processTaskQueue(AbstractNioSelector.java:391)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:315)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler.<clinit>(ReadTimeoutHandler.java:84)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.Connection$ConnectionPipeline.init(Connection.java:782)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:199)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.ConnectionCache.getConnection(ConnectionCache.java:133)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.AsyncKuduClient.newRpcProxy(AsyncKuduClient.java:248)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.AsyncKuduClient.newMasterRpcProxy(AsyncKuduClient.java:272)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.ConnectToCluster.run(ConnectToCluster.java:157)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.AsyncKuduClient.getMasterTableLocationsPB(AsyncKuduClient.java:1350)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.AsyncKuduClient.exportAuthenticationCredentials(AsyncKuduClient.java:651)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.KuduClient.exportAuthenticationCredentials(KuduClient.java:293)
        at org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu.KuduContext$$anon$1.run(KuduContext.scala:97)
        at org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu.KuduContext$$anon$1.run(KuduContext.scala:96)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu.KuduContext.<init>(KuduContext.scala:96)
        at org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu.KuduRelation.<init>(DefaultSource.scala:162)
        at org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:146)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        ... 1 more
18/03/02 10:23:27 WARN client.ConnectToCluster: Unable to find the leader master 172.17.0.43:7077; will retry

Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-e1dfaec7a544> in <module>()
----> 1 df = sqlContext.read.format('org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu').options(**{"kudu.master":"172.17.0.43:7077", "kudu.table":"impala::default.logika_dataset_kudu"}).load()

/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.232957/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in load(self, path, format, schema, **options)
    163             return self._df(self._jreader.load(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
    164         else:
--> 165             return self._df(self._jreader.load())
    166
    167     @since(1.4)

/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.232957/lib/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1134
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.232957/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.232957/lib/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    317                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    320             else:
    321                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o59.load.
: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: org.apache.kudu.client.NoLeaderFoundException: Master config (172.17.0.43:7077) has no leader. Exceptions received: org.apache.kudu.client.RecoverableException: [peer master-172.17.0.43:7077] encountered a read timeout; closing the channel
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu.KuduContext.<init>(KuduContext.scala:96)
        at org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu.KuduRelation.<init>(DefaultSource.scala:162)
        at org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:146)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kudu.client.NoLeaderFoundException: Master config (172.17.0.43:7077) has no leader. Exceptions received: org.apache.kudu.client.RecoverableException: [peer master-172.17.0.43:7077] encountered a read timeout; closing the channel
        at org.apache.kudu.client.ConnectToCluster.incrementCountAndCheckExhausted(ConnectToCluster.java:272)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.ConnectToCluster.access$100(ConnectToCluster.java:49)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.ConnectToCluster$ConnectToMasterErrCB.call(ConnectToCluster.java:349)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.ConnectToCluster$ConnectToMasterErrCB.call(ConnectToCluster.java:338)
        at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred.doCall(Deferred.java:1280)
        at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred.runCallbacks(Deferred.java:1259)
        at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred.handleContinuation(Deferred.java:1315)
        at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred.doCall(Deferred.java:1286)
        at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred.runCallbacks(Deferred.java:1259)
        at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred.callback(Deferred.java:1002)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.KuduRpc.handleCallback(KuduRpc.java:238)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.KuduRpc.errback(KuduRpc.java:292)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.RpcProxy.failOrRetryRpc(RpcProxy.java:388)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.RpcProxy.responseReceived(RpcProxy.java:217)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.RpcProxy.access$000(RpcProxy.java:60)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.RpcProxy$1.call(RpcProxy.java:132)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.RpcProxy$1.call(RpcProxy.java:128)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.Connection.cleanup(Connection.java:694)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.Connection.exceptionCaught(Connection.java:439)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.Connection.handleUpstream(Connection.java:239)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.exceptionCaught(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:153)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireExceptionCaught(Channels.java:536)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler.readTimedOut(ReadTimeoutHandler.java:236)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler$ReadTimeoutTask$1.run(ReadTimeoutHandler.java:276)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.ChannelRunnableWrapper.run(ChannelRunnableWrapper.java:40)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.processTaskQueue(AbstractNioSelector.java:391)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:315)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.kudu.client.RecoverableException: [peer master-172.17.0.43:7077] encountered a read timeout; closing the channel
        at org.apache.kudu.client.Connection.exceptionCaught(Connection.java:412)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler.<clinit>(ReadTimeoutHandler.java:84)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.Connection$ConnectionPipeline.init(Connection.java:782)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:199)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.ConnectionCache.getConnection(ConnectionCache.java:133)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.AsyncKuduClient.newRpcProxy(AsyncKuduClient.java:248)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.AsyncKuduClient.newMasterRpcProxy(AsyncKuduClient.java:272)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.ConnectToCluster.run(ConnectToCluster.java:157)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.AsyncKuduClient.getMasterTableLocationsPB(AsyncKuduClient.java:1350)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.AsyncKuduClient.exportAuthenticationCredentials(AsyncKuduClient.java:651)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.KuduClient.exportAuthenticationCredentials(KuduClient.java:293)
        at org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu.KuduContext$$anon$1.run(KuduContext.scala:97)
        at org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu.KuduContext$$anon$1.run(KuduContext.scala:96)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu.KuduContext.<init>(KuduContext.scala:96)
        at org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu.KuduRelation.<init>(DefaultSource.scala:162)
        at org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:146)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        ... 1 more
```

### Case 2: using spark-shell (Spark 1.6.0 standalone):

```
$ spark-shell --master spark://localhost:7077 --packages org.apache.kudu:kudu-spark_2.10:1.1.0
> import org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu._
> import org.apache.kudu.client._
> import collection.JavaConverters._
> val df = sqlContext.read.options(Map("kudu.master" -> "localhost:7051","kudu.table" -> "impala::default.test")).kudu
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [dataset: string, id: string, itemnumber: string, srcid: string, timestamp: string, year: string, month: string, day: string, week: string, quarter: string, season: string, city: string, region1: string, region2: string, region3: string, region4: string, locality: string, itemname: string, itembqu: string, product_category: string, amount: string, mapped_zipcode: string, latitude: string, longitude: string, depositor_code: string, depositor_name: string, customer_code: string, is_island: string]
```

It seems to be connecting, as it is able to show the column names, but if I

```
// register a temporary table and use SQL
df.registerTempTable("test")
val filteredDF = sqlContext.sql("select count(*) from test").show()
```

bang!

```
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 6) / 6]
Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, tt-slave-2.novalocal, executor 1): org.apache.kudu.client.NonRecoverableException: RPC can not complete before timeout: KuduRpc(method=GetTableSchema, tablet=null, attempt=30, DeadlineTracker(timeout=30000, elapsed=27307), Traces: 

[0ms] querying master, 
[48ms] Sub rpc: GetMasterRegistration sending RPC to server Kudu Master - localhost:7051, 
[71ms] Sub rpc: GetMasterRegistration received from server Kudu Master - localhost:7051 response 
Network error: 
[Peer Kudu Master - localhost:7051] Connection reset, 
[75ms] delaying RPC due to Service unavailable: Master config (localhost:7051) has no leader. 
Exceptions received: org.apache.kudu.client.RecoverableException: 
[Peer Kudu Master - localhost:7051] Connection reset, 

...
(SAME MESSAGE REPEATS 25 TIMES)
...

[24262ms] querying master, 
[24262ms] Sub rpc: GetMasterRegistration sending RPC to server Kudu Master - localhost:7051, 
[24263ms] Sub rpc: GetMasterRegistration received from server Kudu Master - localhost:7051 response 
Network error: 
[Peer Kudu Master - localhost:7051] Connection reset, 
[24263ms] delaying RPC due to Service unavailable: Master config (localhost:7051) has no leader. 
Exceptions received: org.apache.kudu.client.RecoverableException: 
[Peer Kudu Master - localhost:7051] Connection reset, 
[24661ms] trace too long, truncated)

        at org.apache.kudu.client.AsyncKuduClient.tooManyAttemptsOrTimeout(AsyncKuduClient.java:961)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.AsyncKuduClient.delayedSendRpcToTablet(AsyncKuduClient.java:1203)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.AsyncKuduClient.access$800(AsyncKuduClient.java:110)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.AsyncKuduClient$RetryRpcErrback.call(AsyncKuduClient.java:764)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.AsyncKuduClient$RetryRpcErrback.call(AsyncKuduClient.java:754)
        at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred.doCall(Deferred.java:1278)
        at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred.runCallbacks(Deferred.java:1257)
        at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred.callback(Deferred.java:1005)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.GetMasterRegistrationReceived.incrementCountAndCheckExhausted(GetMasterRegistrationReceived.java:156)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.GetMasterRegistrationReceived.access$300(GetMasterRegistrationReceived.java:45)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.GetMasterRegistrationReceived$GetMasterRegistrationErrCB.call(GetMasterRegistrationReceived.java:236)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.GetMasterRegistrationReceived$GetMasterRegistrationErrCB.call(GetMasterRegistrationReceived.java:225)
        at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred.doCall(Deferred.java:1278)
        at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred.runCallbacks(Deferred.java:1257)
        at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred.callback(Deferred.java:1005)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.KuduRpc.handleCallback(KuduRpc.java:220)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.KuduRpc.errback(KuduRpc.java:274)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.TabletClient.failOrRetryRpc(TabletClient.java:770)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.TabletClient.failOrRetryRpcs(TabletClient.java:747)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.TabletClient.cleanup(TabletClient.java:736)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.TabletClient.channelClosed(TabletClient.java:698)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:88)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.TabletClient.handleUpstream(TabletClient.java:679)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler.channelClosed(ReadTimeoutHandler.java:176)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:88)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireChannelClosed(Channels.java:468)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels$6.run(Channels.java:457)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.ChannelRunnableWrapper.run(ChannelRunnableWrapper.java:40)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.processTaskQueue(AbstractNioSelector.java:391)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:315)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kudu.client.NoLeaderFoundException: Master config (localhost:7051) has no leader. Exceptions received: org.apache.kudu.client.RecoverableException: [Peer Kudu Master - localhost:7051] Connection reset
        at org.apache.kudu.client.GetMasterRegistrationReceived.incrementCountAndCheckExhausted(GetMasterRegistrationReceived.java:154)
        ... 32 more
Caused by: org.apache.kudu.client.RecoverableException: [Peer Kudu Master - localhost:7051] Connection reset
        at org.apache.kudu.client.TabletClient.cleanup(TabletClient.java:734)
        ... 21 more
```

As I said, Kudu service is up an running, and I am able to query kudu tables from Hue using Impala.

What am I missing here? Is this the right approach to interfacing Spark with Kudu?

Thanks

Comment: Solved! I was using  the wrong port in case 1 (7051 vs 7077) and, for some strange reason, changing "localhost" to an IP in case 2 solved the issue.